# firebird server 1.5 crash from external source

Tags: sql, firebird

we are running firebird server, version 1.5 and every now and then, we get a firebird crash. Around 100 machines within a 6 hour period, all the same day at around the same time, all have firebird crashes. These machines all have our software installed on them, however some are carrying on as normal, and there is nothing specific to the times they are dying related to anything our software does.

We have tried blocking off port 3050 to any site but us, and this has reduced the frequency at which this happens, making us assume it was people accessing us externally, however, we still are getting it fairly regularly on some machines, which have this port blocked to external unknown traffic.

Is there any way that people could access us externally and cause the service to crash? I know firebird 1.5 is not the most recent version, however these are all around the country so it would be near impossible to upgrade them all, and would take forever and require a rewrite of software.

Any advice regarding firebird security issues that we might be able to block something off, or at least write something to replicate so we can find a way around ourselves, i guess any information regarding ways to make firebird crash without being on the site or being allowed on port 3050 would be a great help.

Thanks

Comment: why do you still use such an old Version? is updating to 2.5.5 no option?

Comment: Unfortunately there are several problems in older versions that can crash Firebird by sending malformed packets. Apart from switching to Classic (process per connection), upgrading to 2.5.5 is probably your only real option. However switching from 1.5 to 2.5 is not something you can do without texting, and it probably requires changes to your application.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your response :) There is just too much work involved to upgrade. I was hoping there might be some additional security i can add, as we have tried closing port 3050 down to anyone who isnt us, but we still get some issues. can people still crash it without access to port 3050? Before we managed to crash it ourselves by sending malformed packets, but once we closed down port 3050 to external srources, we were then unable to do it. is there a way without access to this port? Locking the whole machines down to only our IP address may be the solution if so.